# Using bc from C code

Tags: yacc, bc

I am writing the code for expression evaluator using **lex** and **yacc** which can have following operations:

**/ , * ,  + , - , pow(a,b) , sqrt(a) , log(a)**

also there can be brackets in the expression.

Input expression is in the file "calculator.input"

I have to compare the time of my code with **bc**, I am facing following problems:

1) bc doesn't accept **pow(a,b)** and **log(a)** it instead accepts **a^b** and **l(a)** .
How do I change it?

2) How do I use the **bc** from the main funtion in the **yacc** program ? or that can't be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to change your code than to change `bc`, but if you want to try, you can find pointers to `bc`'s source bundles on the [GNU project page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/) and in the [FreeBSD source mirror](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/usr.bin/bc). Of course, the end result would not strictly speaking be `bc` any more, so I don't know if it would still count, for the purposes of your assignment.

I don't know what the specifications are for the `pow` function you are supposed to implement, but note that `bc`'s `^` operator only allows integer exponents, so it might not work on all your test cases (unless, of course, all your test cases have integer exponents.) You could compute `a^b` with `e(l(a)*b)`, but it won't be as accurate for integer exponents:

```
e(l(10)*100)
99999999999999999920085453156357924020916787698393558126052191252537\
96016108317256511712576426623511.11829711443225035170
10^100
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000
```

You might want to consult with your tutor, professor, or teaching assistant.

If you don't want to (or are not allowed to) generate the `bc` equivalent test cases by hand, you might be able to automate the process with `sed` (if the exponential sub-expressions are not complicated), or by adapting your calculator to output the expression in `bc`'s syntax. The latter would be a fairly easy project, and you'd probably learn something by implementing it.

If you are using a Unix-like system, you can easily run any command-line utility from a C program. (Indeed, you can do that on non-Unix-like systems, too, but the library functions will differ.) If you don't need to pass data to `bc` through its `stdin`, you can use the [`popen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) library function, which is certainly the easiest solution.

Otherwise, you will have to set up a pair of [`pipe(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)s (one for writing to `bc`'s `stdin` and the other for reading from its `stdout`), [`fork(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) a child process, and use one of the [`exec*`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) function calls, probably `execlp(3)` or `execvp(3)`, to run `bc` in the child. (Watch out for pipe deadlock while you are writing to and reading from the child.) Once the child process finishes (which you'll notice because you'll get an EOF on the pipe you're using to read from its `stdout`, you should use [`wait(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wait.3p.html) or `waitpid(3)` to get its status code.

If all that seems too complicated, you could use the much simpler solution of running both your program and `bc` from your shell. (You can use the `time` shell built-in on Unix-like shells to get a measure of execution time, although it will not be microsecond resolution which might be necessary for such a simple program.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer : ) . I am allowed to use time from shell.  Can you please upvote the question?